# Difference entre « poulpe » et « pieuvre » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, zoologie

Quelle est la difference entre « poulpe » et « pieuvre » ? Les deux mots désignent certaines espèces de céphalopodes mais est-ce qu'il y a quelque chose de systématique/biologique/cladistique qui distingue ces termes ?

Comment: *Céphalopode*, *cladistique*... tu... connais manifestement ces termes. Donc... tu connais très certainement la réponse à ta question... ou alors... c'est moi qui n'ai pas compris ta question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

« Poulpe » est une synonyme courant du mot « pieuvre ». Il peut désigner des éléments de l'espèce ayant une petite taille ou une taill moyenne ou même une grande taille ; lorsque l'on parle de l'animal que l'on trouve dans les poissonneries on ne l'appelle pas « pieuvre » mais « poulpe »; on ne dit pas par exemple « Il y avait de la pieuvre dans le plat de riz que nous avons mangé à midi. » On dit « Il y avait du poulpe….». Dans les histoires fantastiques on n'utilise que le mot « pieuvre ».

[Quelques informations en français sur la pieuvre](https://www.pratique.fr/pieuvre-poulpes.html)

Answer (score 8):

> Brusquement une large viscosité ronde et plate sortit de dessous
>   la crevasse. C'était le centre, les cinq lanières s'y rattachaient
>   comme des rayons à un moyeu, on distinguait au côté opposé de ce
>   disque immonde le commencement de trois autres tentacules, restés sous
>   l'enfoncement du rocher. Au milieu de cette viscosité il y avait deux
>   yeux qui regardaient. 
> Ces yeux voyaient Gilliatt.
>  Gilliatt
>   reconnut la pieuvre.
>
> [ Victor Hugo, *Les travailleurs de la mer*, [à la p. 370](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6437586d/f388.image) ]

C'est à Victor Hugo que l'on doit l'introduction en français du mot [*pieuvre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/pieuvre) provenant du parler des [îles anglo-normandes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8Eles_Anglo-Normandes#Langues) (par exemple le mot existait antérieurement à Guernesey sous la forme *peurve, pièvre*, à côté des formes normandes), dans l'extrait qui précède en 1866. « Le mot [[*pieuvre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pieuvre)], [issu de du latin *polypus*, et ayant donné par emprunt *polype* et par évolution *poulpe*], désigne le *poulpe commun*, surtout lorsqu'il est de grande taille ». Le [*poulpe*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poulpe) est une réfection savante de *poupe*, *poulpre* du provençal *pourpre*, *poupre* représentant le latin *polypus* : avec le sens de mollusque il a supplanté le *polype* et est en concurrence avec *pieuvre*, mais comme on l'a dit [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/33014) en cuisine on dit *poulpe* ( (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. A. Rey, Le Robert, 2011, pour l'ensemble des idées de cette reformulation d'éléments trouvés à *pieuvre* et *poulpe*).

Par ailleurs, on nous explique aussi sur Wikipédia que :

> Pieuvre (f) et poulpe (m) sont des noms vernaculaires ambigus désignant
>   en français certains céphalopodes benthiques du sous-ordre Incirrina
>   (principalement la famille des Octopodidae) [...]
>   [...]
>   Ces deux appellations ne sont pas également usitées selon les régions
>   et ne concernent pas tous les octopodes des côtes atlantiques et
>   méditerranéennes françaises. En général, « poulpe » a évolué en
>   appellation surtout commerciale et gastronomique, concernant notamment
>   le poulpe commun. Toutefois l'animal vivant est encore désigné par «
>   poulpe » depuis la Camargue jusqu'à la frontière italienne, alors que
>   « pieuvre » domine ailleurs. En Corse on dit « polpu » prononcé
>   *polpou*. On désigne par « poulpe » surtout les espèces de la famille des octopodidés, soit la plus grande famille d'octopodes, rassemblant
>   plus de 200 espèces. Les espèces de cette famille ont notamment comme
>   point commun leur mode de vie benthique, mais le terme « poulpe » peut
>   aussi désigner des espèces du super-ordre *Incirrina* puisqu'elles
>   partagent avec la famille *Octopodidae* certains caractères, hormis
>   leur mode de vie benthique. Tandis que les espèces de l'autre
>   sous-ordre (*Cirrina*), les cirrates, ne sont donc pas des poulpes
>   puisqu'elles possèdent des cirres, une ombrelle et des nageoires et
>   ont un mode de vie pélagique.
>
> [ Wikipédia, article [*Pieuvre*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pieuvre#%C3%89tymologie_et_appellations), contenu soumis à la licence
>   CC-BY-SA 3.0, note et liens omis ]

Enfin on peut observer qu'au GDT l'article sur [poulpe](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1198907) contient (au bas de la page) une référence au taxon latin Octopus [sp.](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8479766) (abréviation du latin *species*, [on précise](https://www.aquaportail.com/definition-1630-sp.html) « se dit d'un organisme identifié uniquement au niveau du genre » : *espèce non identifiée de*... etc.) alors que celui sur [pieuvre](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8402783) réfère à [Octopus vulgaris](https://www.sealifebase.ca/summary/Octopus-vulgaris.html) (dont les [noms communs](https://www.sealifebase.ca/comnames/CommonNamesList.php?ID=58190&GenusName=Octopus&SpeciesName=vulgaris&StockCode=3996) nous ramènent à notre point de départ...).